# javax.mail attach image body mail generate cid image

Tags: image, jakarta-mail, html-email, attachment

I work with javax.mail and I want to attach a image to the mail body.

I get the image with:

```
messageBodyPart.attachFile(loader.getResource("classpath:imgecalcp/fondoencabezado_marron.png").getFile());
```

I have a html file with the body mail

This file is :

```
<div style="padding: 0px">
        <p
            style="align: left; line-height: 16px; font-size: 10px; color: #009900; font-family: Arial;">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <img src="cid:"cidString/>
            [PIE1]
        </p>
    </div>
```

The java class is

```
Random rand = new Random();
Integer cid  = rand.nextInt(10000) + 1;
String cidString = cid.toString();
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse(to));
message.setSubject(subject);            
MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlFinal, "text/html");
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
final DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();  messageBodyPart.attachFile(loader.getResource("classpath:imgecalcp/fondoencabezado_marron.png").getFile());
messageBodyPart.setContentID("<" + cidString + ">");    
messageBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
message.setContent(multipart);  
Transport.send(message);
```

The message send is;

```
<div style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;color:#1F497D;font-weight: bold;">
                    Juan Jos&#233; Herrera Campa
                    </div>
                    <div style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;color:#1F497D;font-weight: bold;">
                    Director General de Costes de Personal y Pensiones P&#250;blicas
                    </div>




    <div style="padding: 0px">
        <p
            style="align: left; line-height: 16px; font-size: 10px; color: #009900; font-family: Arial;">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <img src="cid:"cidString/>
            <br />Por favor considera el medio ambiente antes imprimir este  mail<br />
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
------=_Part_190_22084367.1493884052556
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=fondoencabezado_marron.png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=fondoencabezado_marron.png
Content-ID: <9827>
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```

How do I have to generate the image cid and write it in the html file?

Answer (score 0):

The cid just needs to be unique within the message so it can be a simple sequence number; it doesn't have to be complicated.  You can put it in the html file however you want, e.g., by writing it there when you create the file or by using a macro expansion or variable substitution facility of some sort.

Comment: Can we add inline style to the cid ? Like style="position:absolute z-index:0;"

Comment: It depends on the mail reader.  See [this link](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) for more information.